# Segfault after realloc twice

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

I was trying to write a function which takes an input without length given. ıt works when I try to get a single input,but if I want to get multiple inputs, I get segfault. Below is the code:

```
char* getinput()
    {
    char c,*str=0,*tmp=0;
    int i=0;

    while(c)
    {
            c=getchar();

            if(c!=EOF && c!='\n')
        {
            if(!(tmp=realloc(str,(i+1)*sizeof(char))))
            {
            free(str);
            return NULL;
            }

        str=tmp;
        str[i++]=c;
        }
        else c=0;
    }

    str[i]=0;
    return str;
}
```

When I try to get a single input, I can print the string:

```
string1      
string1
```

When I try to get multiple inputs, I can't:

```
string1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

There is another variable string2. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Which line does the segfault occur at?

Comment: you are 1 byte too short because of nul terminating byte

Comment: `c` is uninitialised, and `getchar()` returns an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that you input *one* character

You'll allocate a buffer of *one* byte, write the character into it then increase the index and do:

```
str[i]=0;
```

at this point `i==1` and you're writing outside `str` allocated bounds : undefined behaviour

I suggest you increase your buffer size by one:

```
if(!(tmp=realloc(str,(i+2)))
```

(and drop `sizeof(char)` bit since it's guaranteed to be 1)

A more efficient technique would be to realloc "from time to time", keeping track of the capacity of the allocated buffer, as most vector allocators do,  instead of each time.